# Update user profile on MongoDB Stitch

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongodb-stitch

I've been able to do a register and login using MongoDB Stitch but I can't find how to update a user's data. I've tried making queries to db.users or db.user but these don't exist.

Is there a method to update a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I communicated with support and they told me that there is no way to update a user's profile as they are stored in a internal database that is not accesible to the developer. I suggested that this must be explained in the guides but they didn't (or I couldn't find it, please comment and I'll edit).

Answer (score 2):

You can manage users via the MongoDB Stitch admin console. It provides an interface for managing existing users, and creating new users with certain authentication providers.

See also [MongoDB Stitch: User Management](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/auth/user-management/#user-management) to view the procedures.

You may also be interested in [Authentication Providers](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/#authentication-providers), which is a list of mechanisms of which a particular user is able to authenticate with. i.e. Google and Facebook OAuth2-based, etc.